# Perfect Tense with since

Tags: word-choice

Could someone explain which one is the correct answer and why

He hasn’t played since he ……… the accident.

a) had b) has had c) has c) had had

thanks

Comment: What would be your choice and why?

Comment: well I would go for b..because the accident is still affecting

Comment: thank you! but I have to say that the test says the answer is a..could it be

Comment: @Laure I'm afraid not.  The correct answer is A.

Comment: thanks for rectifying, I'd read too quickly and misread "the" for "an" ! shame on me !

Answer (score 3):

The only correct answer to my ears is A.

The construction

(Present perfect phrase) since (event)

means

(Time line; x represents the event)

-----x-------(present)

The present perfect phrase is true for all times to the right of the x. (You can say "ever since" to emphasize that it is true for all times to the right of x, no exceptions.)

The dashes continue to the present, which is why the first phrase uses a perfect. The event is discrete, which is why it uses a simple past.

I think the criterion of "does it affect the present" is always relative. Everything affects the present. It affects the present very much that the Big Bang happened, but we use the simple past. In a "since" sentence, there is a feeling that a discrete event in the past has caused effects that continue to today. To emphasize this difference, we use the simple past for the discrete action and the present perfect for the continuous effect.

Comment: thank you hunter! everthing affects the present.:) it is clearer now..so we can say after the word since we use past tense in these sentences.right?

Comment: It is not quite so simple, but a good rule of thumb. A counterexample I can think of is "since you've been gone, ..."